# Describing space complexity of algorithms

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, space-complexity

I am currently a CS major, and I am practising different algorithmic questions. I make sure I try to analyse time and space complexity for every question. 
However, I have a doubt:

1. If there are two steps (steps which call recursive functions for varying size of OP) in the algorithm, i.e.

   ```
      int a = findAns(arr1)
      int b = findAns(arr2)
      return max(a,b);
   ```

   Would the worst time complexity of this be: `O(N1) + O(N2)` or simply, `O(max(N1,N2))`. I ask because at a time, we would be calling the function with only single input array.
2. While calculating worst case space complexity, if it comes out to be, `O(N) + O(logN)`, since `N > logN`, would we discard `O(logN)` or since `logN` is also dependent on `N` and say worst space complexity is `O(N)`, we would say, worst case space complexity to be `O(N)` only.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Sum

Comment: O(f + g) [is the same as](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/11704/111482) O(max(f, g)) if you follow the definition of big O.